# Proof: $A \neq \emptyset \implies A \nsubseteq \emptyset $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I proof that, let $A$ a set and $A \neq \emptyset$, then $A \nsubseteq \emptyset$;

Proof by contradiction: if $A \subseteq \emptyset$ then by [property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330676/proof-by-contradiction-s-subseteq-emptyset-rightarrow-s-emptyset) I have an absurd , in fact by hypothesis $A \neq \emptyset$, therefore $A \nsubseteq \emptyset$.

Or, direct proof: by hypothesis $A \neq \emptyset$, then "$A \nsubseteq \emptyset$ or $ \emptyset \nsubseteq A$", but by [property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330390/proof-by-contradiction-emptyset-subseteq-a) I have only case that $ A \nsubseteq \emptyset$...
Is it correct?
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Why if $A\neq\varnothing$ then $A\nsubseteq \varnothing$ or $\varnothing \nsubseteq A$? I think it requires proof, because $\subseteq$ is not total order. (on set of subsets of $X$. $X$ is arbitary set.)

Comment: Hi @tetori, Ok! Therefore I must prove that $A \nsubseteq \emptyset$, ok? I prove it by contraddiction, so $A \subseteq \emptyset$ then $A = \emptyset$ but by hypothesis $A \neq \emptyset$ and it is contraddiction therefore $A \nsubseteq \emptyset$ Is it correct?

Comment: I think it is correct :)

Comment: Hi @tetori... thank you soo much!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [Dijkstra-Feijen style](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332186/11994), it is easy to rigorously prove that the two are even equivalent: for any set $A$,

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
& A ≠ ∅ \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\text{"expand $≠$ to introduce equality"} \\
& \lnot (A = ∅) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\text{"introduce double inclusion -- suggested by shape of the desired conclusion"} \\
& \lnot (A ⊆ ∅ \land ∅ ⊆ A) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\text{"$∅ ⊆ A$ is always true"} \\
& \lnot (A ⊆ ∅) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\text{"simplify"} \\
& A ⊈ ∅ \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Wow.. this proof is interesting..

Answer (score 7):

Or more positively, if $A\neq\emptyset$ then there exists some $x$ with $x\in A$, and since $x\notin\emptyset$ it follows that $A\not\subseteq\emptyset$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a language issue so I can't quite tell if what you are suggesting is correct or not. In any case, it is not rigorously presented, so I provide you here with a rigorous proof.

Suppose that $A\subseteq \emptyset $. Then, by definition of inclusion, for all $a\in A$ holds that $a\in \emptyset $. However, $a\in \emptyset$ never holds, and thus $a\in A$ never holds, so that $A=\emptyset $. By contrapositive it follows that if $A\ne \emptyset$ then $A$ is not contained in $\emptyset $.

Comment: Hi @Ittay Weiss I corrected my precedent post.... now How is it correct?