# Did I prove this statement correctly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$ be a set.
If $A\subset B$ for any set $B$, then $A=\emptyset$.

Here is my proof.

Suppose to the contrary that $A$ is not an empty set.
Then there exists an element $a$ in $A$.
Now choose $B$ as an empty set.
Then for $a\in A$, $a\notin B$.
So, $A\not\subset B$. This contradicts to the hypothesis.
Thus $A=\emptyset$.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: This is fine, although, the use of a proof by contradiction seems unnecessary, as there is a direct proof (but your proof is fine)

Comment: Are you using $\subset$ as a proper subset? If so, then bear in mind that $\emptyset\not\subset\emptyset$.

Comment: To expand on Max's comment the direct proof is: A $\subset \emptyset$ by hypothesis and $\emptyset \subset A$ (since the empty set is a subset of every set) hence $A = \emptyset$.

Comment: by contrapositive, $A\neq \emptyset \to \exists B: A\nsubseteq B$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331908/proof-a-neq-emptyset-implies-a-nsubseteq-emptyset